# Unable to bring up main application screen after streamlit login screen seperately

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, streamlit

```
proceed=0
def login():
#interface codes for the login screen   
 global proceed
 
    if st.button('Proceed'):
         proceed=1
         st.balloons()
         if proceed==1:
            main()
def main():
#interface codes for the main screen 


if __name__=='__main__' :
                    
               login()
```

Hello friends, I have prepared two interface codes, the login screen, and the main screen. When I press the proceed button on the login screen, I want the login interface to disappear and only the main interface to appear.
When you press the proceed button in the current state of the code, both interfaces appear on one screen. I want only the main screen to appear when I press the proceed button. How can I solve this problem?
**Is there any way to use display:none css property for login screen?**
The login screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   import streamlit as st


def login():
    # interface codes for the login screen
    st.write("Welcome to the login screen")
    global proceed
    if st.button("Proceed"):
        st.session_state["page"] = "main"
        st.balloons()
        st.experimental_rerun()


def main():
    # interface codes for the main screen
    st.write("Welcome to the main screen")


if "page" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["page"] = "login"

if st.session_state["page"] == "login":
    login()
elif st.session_state["page"] == "main":
    main()
```